# Is it possible to use Google Firebase Dynamic Link to route user to app store based on device?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

i've been using Firebase Dynamic Links as a url shortener, plain & simple. but is it possible to use this to send the user to an app that's not mine in the iOS App Store or the Google Play store depending on which device is used when tapping a link?

i have some Google Docs documents that i'm sharing with some folks. i thought it would be nice to present ONE url for them to tap on if they're using a mobile device, to send them to get the Google Docs App.

it seems one would need to be building their own app to utilize this feature, but i thought i'd ask in case there's a way to do it that i'm not finding.

note: this is not a situation where i can program anything that would make the determination; it's either i use the options to make it happen or i just provide the two different links for them.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not depend on Firebase Dynamic Links so much, as it depends on the app and question. If that app implements dynamic links, and publishes allows you to pass document ID, then you can construct such links too. But it's essentially their API at that point, so only the app creator can answer wheter they do this.